# (How) can I link an HREF to an anchor within a PHP generate web page?

Tags: php

I use PHP to generate my web site. I would like to add a link to an anchor within a .PHP page.

(How) can I do that?

Comment: The question is not informative enough. Can you please tell what's the problem? I mean, if you know the URL of the other script and the name of anchor, there shouldn't be a problem. So, what is the scenario?

Comment: I little detail would do no harm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic HTML:

```
<a href='#targetanchor'>Linking from here</a>
...
<a id='targetanchor'>Linking to here</a>
```

Just echo it out in your PHP.

<s>I think you can use ID or name for the target identifier, may be browser-dependent though.</s>

Of course, that's an anchor in the same page.  To do it to a specific place in another page, put in the address:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='whatever.php#targetanchor>Jump to target on whatever</a>";
?>
```

[Another explanation here.](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aabg020899a.htm)

---

Re-reading your question, you may be asking if an anchor can be added with a link to a PHP page.

Of course it can.  The PHP part is just the language that the server is instructed to interpet the page in.  Then it sends regular HTML back to the client browser, who uses the anchors to jump around the HTML document.

Comment: IDs are the correct way to do it, on any visible element. Named anchors are deprecated.

Comment: It's been in the standard since 1999. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Answer (score -1):

If you want html within php, best way is to separate html and php like,

```
<?php
//some php code
?>

<!--html content -->
```

If there is small html within php then you can do like,

```
<?php
echo '<b>Bold stuff</b>';
?>
```

If there is mixing of lot of html and php, then use heredoc,
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc